# Table within form css

Tags: css, forms, html-table, tablerow

I am having a weird problem with CSS.

I am trying to achieve the following.
I can have people search for a name or a part of a quote in a database and I would like to display this into a box (in this case a form ,which is easy for styling).
Problem is, the total box should have a gradient green color, but not the entire fetched data is retrieved with a green layout.

I have debugged and it seems to work just great:
I have both echo and alerted my output and it is just a normal form with table rows in it..

Here's the result outcome:
`pastebin.com/AZAv6bpX` (broken)

Here's my css:
`pastebin.com/NATwyki6` (broken)

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Notice the table rows still continue-ing after the gradient has stopped.

I have adjusted the table entry margins, for the div (results) they are placed in. So I am 100% sure the outcome is as I want it.

So basically I got:

code from pastebin here

And this weird layout.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: -1, sorry: your Pastebin links are dead, which makes this question pretty useless!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either take your `float:left` off of your table or set `overflow:auto` on your form.
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6qJfr/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept this answer in 6 minutes!
Thanks again for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

Because your form contents are set to float, they are taken out of the flow, and so your container will not wrap around them.

The simple fix for your css would be to add in the following;

```
form br { clear:both }
```

and then make sure that you fix the final `</br>` in your form to be `<br />` instead.